How to host well-known file for both android and IOS?
I am working on implementing deep links (Universal Links on iOS) for my Flutter application. The goal is to open the app when a user clicks on my website URLs.
I have already created the required files:

apple-app-site-association for iOS
assetlinks.json for Android
However, I am facing an issue hosting these files on my domain.

Setup:
Backend: Apache web server
Frontend: Angular
When I try to access these files via their URLs (e.g., https://example.com/.well-known/apple-app-site-association or https://example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json), I am redirected to the login page of the website instead of being able to retrieve the files.
Troubleshooting Attempts:
I suspect the issue might be related to routing or authentication in the Angular frontend or the server configuration, but I am unsure how to resolve it.
Question:
How can I correctly host these files under the .well-known/ directory on my domain so they are publicly accessible without triggering redirections or requiring authentication?
Any guidance on configuring Angular and Apache to support this functionality would be greatly appreciated.

You should add .well-known file into public directory of your website and it will be working fine.

Here is the process to do so

Open the server public folder
Create a .well-known folder inside that
Host the file there

in case if the url is redirecting to authenticate try to move the folder in public
